# Get-Set returning null when accessed by a button

Tags: c#, button, get, set

I'm probably missing something simple, but have been messing with this for a few hours and I cannot get the method to return something not null.  When I'm stepping over the process, getDir1 will take the value of the class "swSheetFormatCycle.Form1.FolderUpdate", but getDir1.SwDir remains null so swDir remains null.  Will the button method not set swDir or swTemplate the way I'm doing it?

```
   // Get-Set Class
public class FolderUpdate
{
    private string swDir;
    public string SwDir
    {
        get {return swDir;}
        set {swDir = value;}
    }

    private string swTemplate;
    public string SwTemplate
    {
        get {return swTemplate;}
        set {swTemplate = value;}
    }
}

private void btnTemBrow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog tempBrowse = new OpenFileDialog();
    DialogResult result = tempBrowse.ShowDialog();
    string tempText = tempBrowse.FileName;
    txtTemp.Text = tempText;
    // Setting the template field
    FolderUpdate temUpd = new FolderUpdate();
    temUpd.SwTemplate = tempText;
}

private void btnDirBrow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog dirBrowse = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    DialogResult result = dirBrowse.ShowDialog();
    string dirText = dirBrowse.SelectedPath;
    txtDir.Text = dirText;
    // Setting the directory field
    FolderUpdate dirUpd = new FolderUpdate();
    dirUpd.SwDir = dirText;
}

// Get the directory set by the button method
swSheetFormatCycle.Form1.FolderUpdate getDir1 = new swSheetFormatCycle.Form1.FolderUpdate();
string swDir = getDir1.SwDir;

// Get the template set by the button method
swSheetFormatCycle.Form1.FolderUpdate getDir2 = new swSheetFormatCycle.Form1.FolderUpdate();
string swTemplate = getDir2.SwTemplate;
```

Comment: Since this is a GUI, please tell us the exact workflow of what's happening (it's very unclear when the last four lines of code are being executed). Also, keep in mind that nearly all the variables in your button click methods are local, and they'll get garbage-collected at the end of the method. So they're basically doing absolutely nothing at this point.

Comment: @musical_coder I have two .cs documents in the same solution.  One called Program.cs and the other called Form1.cs.  My Program.cs code runs fine without the GUI.  I have created a Form that when the user clicks the "browse" buttons, the File/Folder dialog boxes open and whatever path they select is placed into the corresponding text boxes.  I have the template and directory hard coded at the moment.  The idea is to have the user use the GUI, and pass in the template and directory string paths to the program.  The calls for the "gets" are from Program.cs

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Unfortunately I'm too busy to give detailed help at the moment, but based on your comment to @Steve below, I think you need sit down with a professor or other experienced programmer to correct some misunderstandings you have about O.O. programming (for example, using `static` for the folders, even if it had somehow worked, isn't the right approach). I myself struggled unnecessarily with GUIs at first because I didn't get help on O.O issues. Sorry I can't do more! Keep at it and you'll get this working (and more importantly, improve your understanding of concepts).

Comment: @musical_coder Okay, I've only been at C# for about 2 weeks since I couldn't accomplish all I wanted with python.  I learn from reading things on here, a few books, snippets of code ... thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button events are creating new instances of your FolderUpdate class and then are not  doing anything with the object and it is abandoned at the end of the method call.

your "// Get the directory set by the button method" code
is also creating **new** instances so they will also be null

Attach the FolderUpdate instance to the form itself so that you can reference it.

```
public class FolderUpdate
{
    .... 
}


public FolderUpdate Folders { get; set; }

private void btnTemBrow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ...
     Folders.SwTemplate = tempText;
}

private void btnDirBrow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ...
     Folders.SwDir = dirText;
}


// Then when you are reading them
var folders = swSheetFormatCycle.Form1.Folders;
string swDir = folders.SwDir;
string swTemplate = folders.SwTemplate;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, feels like it's getting closer.  However, there was a problem. *var folders = swSheetFormatCycle.Form1.Folders* required an object reference.  So I could do the following:

Comment: I could make ***public static FolderUpdate Folders { get; set; }*** and then it would allow that code.  However, on either button click ***Folders.SwTemplate = tempText;*** or ***Folders.SwDir = dirText;*** resulted in null reference errors upon selecting the file or folder paths.  I tried creating a new instance of Form1 and various other means that are probably wrong ... they all ended in errors on the button presses.

Comment: ***public static FolderUpdate Folders = new FolderUpdate();*** then life is good.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: A static field would work but you can also just initialize it in the oninit or have the property getter setter wrap the private field.   This allows you to add additional cleanup logic within the setter getter without having to modify the reset of your implementations. FolderUpdate _folders = new FolderUpdate(); public FolderUpdate Folders { get { return _folders; } set { _folders = value; }   --- or within init ----  Init {    this.Folders = new FolderUpdate();   }

Comment: Thanks for the alternate method.